# Finding element for background-positioning of video

Tags: css, wordpress

Working on this website - http://www.lightindarkness.com/

Trying to get the video to show the top of the clip and can just hide whatever is below the set height. Background-position:cover top; isn't sticking on to the id, classes, or elements i tried. Anyone see what may stick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the video's element, the one with the class "resizelistener", top to 0 on the firefox dev tools and it seems like it did the trick.

Hope it helps.